# gemspec link to specific commit

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In a Gemfile I can do this:

```
gem "html-proofer", :git => "https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer.git", :ref => 'e1c259fc18a083b1f2f1580f0ea5176c72f4fbac'
```

How can I do the same thing in a gemspec with `add_runtime_dependency`?

Comment: You can not do this in gemspec